# handling ErrorException (E_NOTICE) Undefined offset: 0

Tags: api, laravel-5, guzzle

> ```
> I am trying to access the elements within the text JSON reference from the call, for example, I am trying to access the item (content)
> ```
>
> inside the JSON but it continues to show me the error message knowing
>   that the code works and the full text of the JSON file is displayed
>   without problems Is there a similar PHP lavarel method that can be
>   used as an arrylist Or any kind of data structure that is used to
>   obtain the elements within a response

```
$client = new Client();
$request = $client->post('http://localhost:4567/user/login', [
                'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'application/json'],
                'body' => json_encode($data),
          ]);
$request= json_decode($request->getBody(), true);
return $request[0];
```

Comment: Can you show what is in `$request`? Like dd($request) or somthing?

Comment: Thinks you I am used var_dump()

Comment: please put your all function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your code should be like**

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

$client = new Client();
    $request = $client->post('http://localhost:4567/user/login', [
                'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'application/json'],
                'body' => json_encode($data),
            ]);
 return $request->getBody();
```